# Can we combine jQuery-ui and Raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, raphael

I'm trying to use jQuery-ui's dialog and trying to create a rectangle using Raphael in that dialog when a user clicks on a link. The rectangle is getting drawn correctly, but the .attr("fill","#FFFFFF") method is not getting executed. When I run it, the rectangle is not getting filled with black color. Also I'm facing the same problem with .text method. This is happening only in IE. in chrome I'm able to see the color.

Can anybody please tell me if we can use both Raphael and jQuery-ui together? If not what would be the work around?

Any pointer will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: can you post a link to what your working on?

Comment: A bit confused... you say you're using `.attr( "fill", "#FFFFFF" )` but "the rectangle is not getting filled with `black` color".  Have you tried using `.attr( "fill", "#000000" )` instead? #FFFFFF = 'white, #000000 = 'black'